# Placement issue Right and left arrow on below slider using font-awesome

Tags: html, css

I want to make something like this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/crywo.jpg

I can't put these arrows (fa-angle-left) on image as it is on slider. I tried with `position: absolute` and `relative`.

This is my code, the arrows may not work because I used font-awesome.

```css
#top_header {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/wCDfIxa.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  .slider_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    img {
      width: 100%;
      border: 0;
      padding: 4em 0;
    }
    a {
      .fa-angle-left, .fa-angle-right {
        font-size: 80px;
        color: yellow;
      }
      .fa-angle-left {
        float: left;
      }
      .fa-angle-right {
        float: right;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="top_header" class="clearfix">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider_wrapper">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bPbklqm.png" alt="">
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what do you need ? add some descriptions add jsfiddle add images :|

Comment: *isn't working well* is not enough. What exactly is happening?

Comment: What happened when you added the position absolute? What where the expected results?

Comment: When I added position: relative to .slider_wrapper and position: absolute to .fa-angle-left and .fa-angle-right then arrows were in yellow background  but still under img. I want arrows in the image like it is in slider http://i.imgur.com/WSXT8xt.png - img

Comment: If the arrows are in the right position in your page, but behind your image then you either need to give the arrows a `z-index`. Since your image has a z-index of 1 by default, I would give your arrows a z-index of 2.

Comment: Now, When I added position: relative to the .slider_wrapper and position: absolute to .fa-angle-left, right I don't see arrows ;o. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu In your fiddle you don't link up the cdn properly [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/0jz9spo3/1/ ] I also placed the a tag with span fa after the silder_wrapper div. And change the css. If you have any question ask me in comment,

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Thanks! Now I have something like this: http://i.imgur.com/24SZOc5.png and still i don't know how to put correctly these arrows in the middle of img

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu You see the fiddle. Then something wrong with your code. Are you working on live link or on localhost ??

Comment: @MostafaBaezid localhost, When I want add text over an image then I don't have problem with positions, only with these arrows i have a problem.

Comment: Add those a tag before the wrapper [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/0jz9spo3/3/ ] and in css fa-angle-left,
.fa-angle-right {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  margin-top:22.5%;
  
}

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Almost, but it must looks like that: http://i.imgur.com/uyJDvDK.png I think that these arrows must be in .slider_wrapper. Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu if I placed it inside silder_wrapper then I have to use position absolute also. [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/0jz9spo3/4/  ]

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Thanks ! May I ask you if I have problems with coding ?

Comment: sure. :) so is it working on your side?

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Ye, now it's working, thanks !

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu sounds good. So I can post it as a answer :)

Comment: @MostafaBaezid i.imgur.com/uyJDvDK.png I think that this text and span should be in the middle of image, also text should be centered (shouldn't go beyond .slider_wrapper and img ), not outside the image, like it is there. What do you think ? What am I doing wrong ? jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/0jz9spo3/8

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu delete the width from h2 add left:0; and change margin-top:32;
BTW span inside h2 tag is not looks good. and use class if you use only h2 span then it will be affect on your other h2 span . :) If you have any question ask me on my answer comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/**  - - - - - - - - - - Top Header - - - - - - - - - - **/

#top_header {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/wCDfIxa.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider_wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.fa-angle-left,.fa-angle-right {
  font-size: 40px !important;/*Dont use !important when you working on  different style sheet */
  color: white;
  position:absolute;
   margin-top:22.5%;
}

.fa-angle-left {
left:7%;
}

.fa-angle-right {
  right:7%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <section id="top_header" class="clearfix">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider_wrapper">
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-angle-left "></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bPbklqm.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <!--slider_wrapper End-->

  </div>
</section>

    <!--slider_wrapper End-->

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I did what you said above and now I have something like this: http://i.imgur.com/8iy8LGw.png - span with h2 doesn't want to center and span is beyond .slider_wrapper and img. http://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/0jz9spo3/10/

Comment: you don't set left:0;

Comment: I have left; 0 in h2 on localhost but it does nothing, any ideas. I want to do like it is in this image: http://i.imgur.com/uyJDvDK.png

Comment: Ok i will give your answer soon coz it's 3.20Am here. So need to sleep. Tomorrow you will get you answer.

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu check the html section and css section. If any question regarding this ask me.

Comment: I gave h2 - width: 100% and span- width: 100% and margin: 0 auto width display: block; because span must to cover the entire width of .slider_wrapper, also I gave h2 text-align: center and it's not centered. What am I doing wrong ? http://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/0jz9spo3/12/   I want to do as it is shown in this image: http://i.imgur.com/uyJDvDK.png What is wrong ?

Comment: Ohh sorry I dnt attached the link. We need to use position absolute and relative .. i have changed it for you.. [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/hyuk0qtm/2/ ]

Comment: Thanks, jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/hyuk0qtm/4 here is working but on my localhost I have still this: i.imgur.com/9pInhbX.png flees to the right side. The left side is glued but the right side is not, max-width doesn't help.

Comment: did you add this position relative on .slider_wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
} if you remove this position relative from your current fiddle then you will face that problem like the image one.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I have problem with float in my news section. I have section called news (Aktualnosci). . I want to set image (img has div with float: left and box-shadow) to the left side and content (content has div with float: right ) to the right side. If I want set img float: left and add box-shadow to img div and also when I add float: right to content div then I have something like this: http://i.imgur.com/55sZv8W.png But If I delete float: left from img div then I have this: imgur.com/7jFc09S What am I doing wrong ? https://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/hyuk0qtm/7/ i.imgur.com/ZwcMJYa.png

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu actually I'm confused. I mean I don't understand what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve this: i.imgur.com/ZwcMJYa.png But I have problem with float. Actually When I added float: left to the img and float: right to the right div with main content then I have this: http://i.imgur.com/55sZv8W.png I gave width: 40% to img div and 40% to content div btw.

Comment: I'm not using framework, its only html/css without framework. I noticed that as I will remove padding from news section(yellow div) then img and main content section is outside yellow div, it should be in yellow div and then float: left and float: right is working well ;o

Comment: I noticed that img div and main content div falls out from yellow div when I add float: left to img section but if it does not have float: left then img section is correctly in yellow div

Comment: I did it I think, .news_img {
            background-color: red;
            width: 30%;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        
        .news_article {
            background-color: aqua;
            width: 30%;
            display:inline-block;
            float: right;
        }  I deleted float: left from .news_img and added display: inline-block, also added display: inline-block in .news_article and float: right and its working, I did it good or something can do better with this code ?

Comment: I think I got actually what you want.. Are you trying to make one page web. when you click a nav element it will goes to that section ??

Comment: yea, one page web. Whether it is possible to do such line in css as it is in this image or I have to cut this line in photoshop and code it as a image or background ?? http://i.imgur.com/BFIbqsI.png

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/stnfumh4/1/ ] just a demo 1st two link will be work when you click on them. Please take a look. I hope you got it. and One more thing I just add the header as fixed which means it will be move when you scroll. And Searching on google " One Page HTML/css web page example " you will find lot's info about it. Any Question ask me anytime :)

Comment: I got it, thanks. Whether it is possible to do such line in css as it is in this image or I have to cut this line in photoshop and code it as a image or background ?? i.imgur.com/BFIbqsI.png ?

Comment: actually never work on it But maybe possible with css. Not sure. If i found something I will let you know here .. :(

Comment: Ok, I thought about <img> or background-image. I think that I will set it as an image and I will must do position: relative and absolute and set so that each div float: left and float: right as it is in this image - i.imgur.com/BFIbqsI.png What do you think ? Do you understand me ?

Comment: As a background image you can set it. :) try it if you face Any problem I will help you :)

Comment: Hey, I have a question to you. How I can to set this line in the center ? - I mean : http://i.imgur.com/BFIbqsI.png I set this line as a background in div backgorund-position: center doesn't work for me, any advice ? PAstebin: html - http://pastebin.com/FfYQ7Ba2 CSS : http://pastebin.com/NchgXWik Is it a good way in html ? Thanks!

Comment: or set this line as an <img> in <span> - <span id="img_wrapper><img src=""></span> As will be better?

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu make fiddle with your code and live image url

Comment: Ok, I did fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/stnfumh4/2/ and I want to achieve something like this: http://i.imgur.com/BFIbqsI.png Line should be in the center with position relative I think and divs with position: absolution.

Comment: I Think that I resolved my problem, I don't how.. but it's working haha :D

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu spelling mistake background-position

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu one more suggestion right now your html section is not responsive for many reason .. mainly those img that you used <img src="URL" alt="sometext " /> how ever its good to make a class for img tag those are using in your html you can try this in HTML <img class="img-responsive" src="url" alt="text" /> and add this .img-responsive{   max-width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
   height: auto;}  in your css part. This will help you to make those images responsive. :) Good luck

Comment: Thanks for advice. I have problem, It's mean I think that can do it better, there is a lot of css code. https://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/stnfumh4/3/ - section qualiffications. I don't know how to  do seperate qualification: e12, e13, e14 without <br> and without margin-top: 80rem. I mean this: #qualifications_wrapper #qualifications .qualification_2 {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40rem;
  width: 46%;
} and  this: #qualifications_wrapper #qualifications .qualification_3 {
  float: left;
  margin: 57rem 0;

Comment: I Want to do each subsequent div in new line that were all under each other https://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/stnfumh4/4/

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu  so now you're solving problem alone. That's good. quick learner :) Keep it up :)

Comment: I have problem with hexagons, can you help me ?  I want to do this (I mean these positions of hexagons) : http://i.imgur.com/KMDCDJX.png Right now I have something like this: http://i.imgur.com/oTQ55vH.png  I want to have this images in the center of this yellow div.

Comment: I did this by using percentages and divs are not perfectly in the middle: http://i.imgur.com/jvL17C6.png And why rest of this divs is outside the yellow container ?

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu please add a fiddle with your image always. Coz I don't know what actually inside your code. So I make a demo for you. I don't know what I have done in here [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/vv8fuqpb/2/ ]. So just go through with your Image. Maybe lot's of unnecessary code there. Don't know if this will help you or not. But I love to do this hahaha :)

Comment: I did this: https://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/vv8fuqpb/3/ and my question is: Can I do it better ? Another, easier way ? I think that can do that with less amount of  code. What do you think ? I did it good ?

Comment: Yes of course you did something good. But It's not responsive. And I thought you have create those hexagons with css. So I create those hexagons with css and place those image. If I have those Image before then my code is [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/4w9ak60p/1/ ] and also media screen. when screen will get 475px all those images are below each other. And Now days every web need to be responsive. Hope this will help you.

Comment: oooo Thanks a lot ! I would like to ask you how to do: fourth and fifth img-box more in the middle, I mean Fourth img-box should be between first and second, fifth img-box should be between second and third :nth-child(4) don't work for me.

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu on your code 4th and 5th image are center

Comment: I think that I done responsive for max-width: 475px. http://kuba-test.cba.pl/ What's now ? For min-width: 476px and max-width: 768px ?

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu ur site is not responsive [ http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fkuba-test.cba.pl%2F ] See this.

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu Why this ad appear at the top? Are you connected with google adsense or affiliate marketing ??

Comment: I'm not connected with google, this is free hosting that i didn't have to pay for hosting and then they put advertisement. They are cashing in on the ads.  http://i.imgur.com/H7EVGN1.png On localhost it's responsive ;d

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu do you mind if I copy you site on my local host??

Comment: You can copy it. I just do it as an exercise When I do it in 100% responsive then I will try to add some animation on site.

Comment: Now what ? I have to do responsive for min-width: 476px and max-width: 768px ? I'm Right ?

Comment: in you media query replace the max-width:475 with 768px and see. Coz responsive start with 768px

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu I think your problem is fix after adding that. On my side everything is ok if I set max-width: 768px on media query :) good luck for next animation part :)

Comment: I've got problem with my mobile menu. http://i.imgur.com/XYvwqLp.png I want to change color background of ul - yellow color -  Code: <ul class="mobimenu inrwrpr mnuopn" style="z-index: 9999; background-color: rgb(234, 214, 54); transition: 0.5s;"> I see this when I want to inspect element in chrome, but I don't see this code in my editor, how to change this ?

Comment: you need to place that code under media query ul.mobimenu{z-index: 9999; background-color: yellow; transition: 0.5s;}

Comment: @MustafaBaezid This only works if I add !important behind color. How I can remove style from <a>  In css I did : .mobimenu .inrwrpr .mnuopn a{ color: red; } and it's not working ;/ http://i.imgur.com/XYvwqLp.png

Comment: I dn't understand where is color red ??

Comment: I want to change color of link -a : http://i.imgur.com/OCCSdTk.png and it's styled in html but I don't see this code in html so how to change color of this link in css ?

Comment: it's inline css overwrite your color black.. Use !important

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/657qmv5.png I Want to put .circle and .qualification_title in blue box called .qualiffication_header_box but i can't... how to do it ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/whtcu1zv/1/ Here is my code How to put this circle into pink div ? Title is in pink div but circle is not in pink div

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu I will help you tomorrow. Try position absolute on . circle and relative on the class that contain pink div. Its 2.45Am need rest. Tomorrow 2 morning I have an appointment with my client. They came to from dubai so Just making a presentation for them. Hope you understand. But I will help you sure But tomorrow. :) good nyt mate.

Comment: When I added position: absolute to circle and relative to pink div then circle was under blue div  ;p Okay, good night to you too.

Comment: So, what's with my problem ? Can you help ?

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu sorry for late reply. Busy day.. Let me check on your fiddle. So you want to put that circle inside the pink div. Let me try my method Will update the fiddle soon .

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/bgz8wkwk/1/  ] Found one unnecessary closing </div> so I make that as a section ending tag and remove you image class and make it img-responsive. And lots of css need  to remove specially the problem is you make two .circle css and used position relative on two css class so I remove them. Please check with your fiddle. Thanks

Comment: Thanks now I know how to it good. Can I make such a container in css like this ? http://i.imgur.com/qjfmj2R.gif

Comment: Yes you can make this with css.

Comment: I tried with transform: rotate(); but it does not work as I want

Comment: I tried with this: http://codepen.io/jeremyfrank/pen/zvdXZM But clip-path is not working for me EDIT : // I did it by adding -webkit- Clip-path is working only in chrome ? Is it true ?

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu this is not you tried. this is you find in google search. [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/pr232x93/1/ ] here is my demo. Good luck. Try your self .

Comment: I have question to this: https://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/bgz8wkwk/2/  What if I will change width of pink div to 50% and then I want center this div ? What do I need to change in this to achieve it ?

Comment: I don't find any pink div in this fiddle. If you make a width of pink div 50% and then you may use margin:0 px auto; display: block; for the element. Or you may use text-align: center;

Comment: Ohh my bad ;p I mean yellow div - jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/bgz8wkwk/2 But if I change in yellow div display: from inline-block to block then the yellow container breaks ;d so how to do it well ?

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu check the css section [ http://jsfiddle.net/3ywrckce/1/ ] check where I have make changes. :)

Comment: but I want center yellow container, not circle in the yellow container, and if I change .qualification_header from display: inline-block to display: block then yellow container breaks

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu check CSS section  #qualifications .qualifications_wrapper .qualification_1_box .qualification_header  change display inline-block to block and add margin:0 auto; then let me know

Comment: I have done it many times, when I change what u said I have this: http://i.imgur.com/ivLDxLI.png

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu http://jsfiddle.net/3ywrckce/2/ then how it's work when I add this :/

Comment: Sure, its working but if I want add float: left to the .qualification_box_title then I have to add float: left to the circle, also I must change display to inline-block and I must change in .qualification_header: from display: block to inline-block. I want to have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/bgz8wkwk/2/ but yellow this must be centered, nothing more ;p Circle and .qualification_title must be float: left;

Comment: When you add float left that div gose to left so the you dont need display-inline block

Comment: Ok, but still it doesn't solve my problem I want to have circle float: left and title - e12 floated to the left,. I know that I must change display: inline-block to block in .qualification_header then I will be able to set this div in the center but if I do this then yellow div crashes ;/ http://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/bgz8wkwk/2/

Comment: #qualifications .qualifications_wrapper .qualification_1_box .qualification_header .circle AND #qualifications .qualifications_wrapper .qualification_1_box .qualification_header .qualification_box_title 

check  [ http://jsfiddle.net/3ywrckce/3/  ]

Comment: I do not know what you mean, I checked your fiddle and something is wrong bcs circle is on top. I centered this yellow div by deleting display: inline-block but I can't float to the left title http://i.imgur.com/0fTren5.png ohh

Comment: it is probably impossible to center the yellow container with title and circle floated to the left ;O. When I changing display: inline-block to block everything will smashes http://i.imgur.com/jPQKMCw.png

Comment: @last.k1ng.k1xu sorry mate confused about your question

Comment: I mean I dont know how to solve my problem ;/ I can't cope with this, always something is wrong. I know that yellow div must have display: block then it will able to set this div in the center, but if i set display: block then everything is wrong... Can you help me solve this problem ?

Comment: Sorry mate maybe this time I'm confused. Make a new post . Maybe someone help you out. :(

Comment: You don't know how to do it or you don't know what I want to achieve ? ;/

Comment: I don't know what actually you want achive

Comment: all I need is to center this yellow container - http://jsfiddle.net/Kiksu/bgz8wkwk/2/ nothing more. I did it a little different but I would like to know how to do it. I'm going to sleep right now, so good night.